# How to plot top 5 most frequent variables by region in R

Tags: r

I am looking to do a plot to look into the most common occuring FINAL_CALL_TYPE in my dataset by BOROUGH in NYC. I have a dataset with over 3 million obs. I broke this down into a sample of 2000, but have refined it even more to just the incident type and the borough it occured in.

Essentially, I want to create a plot that will visualize to the 5 most common call types in each borough, with the count of how many of each call types there was in each borough.

**Below is a brief look of how my data looks with just Call Type and Borough**

```
> head(df)
        FINAL_CALL_TYPE   BOROUGH
1804978          INJURY     BRONX
1613888          INJMAJ  BROOKLYN
294874           INJURY  BROOKLYN
1028374            DRUG  BROOKLYN
1974030          INJURY MANHATTAN
795815             CVAC     BRONX
```

**This shows how many unique values there are**

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   2000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ FINAL_CALL_TYPE: Factor w/ 139 levels "ABDPFC","ABDPFT",..: 50 48 50 34 50 25 17 138 28 28 ...
 $ BOROUGH        : Factor w/ 5 levels "BRONX","BROOKLYN",..: 1 2 2 2 3 1 4 2 4 4 ...
```

**This is the code that I have tried**

```
> ggplot(df, aes(x=BOROUGH, y=FINAL_CALL_TYPE)) +
+     geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
+     facet_grid(~BOROUGH)
```

and below is the result
[image: R Plot - Call type by borough]

I have tried a few suggestions accross this community, but I have not found any that shows how to perform the action with 2 columns.

It would be much appreciated if there is someone who know a solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your y-axis variable is a factor, which doesn't really make sense. You've got borough on both the x-axis and as the facetting variable—unless there are smaller groups in here (e.g. that you'd be mapping to fill), you probably only want one of these. If you're trying to plot counts, remove `stat = "identity"`, since that tells `geom_bar` that there's some numeric value already calculated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use tidyverse to doo something like:

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(BOROUGH, FINAL_CALL) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    top_n(n = 5, wt = count)
```

then plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = FINAL_CALL, y = count) +
    geom_col() +
    facet(~BOROUGH, scales = "free")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need it to do. Thanks!

Comment: with column/bar plots you should be careful using `scales = free`, i suggest using `scales = free_x` instead. It can be deceptive to have facets next to each other that have very different y axis scales. The height of the bars generally understood to be comparable, and the fact that the axis tick labels vary across facets is often overlooked by casual viewers of the plot.

Comment: Agree with Lief in principal, but should be explored for what you are trying show with the plot

Answer (score 2):

## creating the barplot

The first part of your problem is to create the barplot. With `geom_bar` you only need to supply the x variable, as the y-axis is the count of observations of that variable. You can then use the facet option to separate that count into different panels for another grouping variable.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = color)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(.~cut)
```

## filtering to top 5 observations

The second part of your problem, limiting the data to only the top five in each group is slightly more complex. An easy way to do this is to first `tally` the data which will create a column `n` that has the count of observations. By adding the sort option we can `filter` the data to the first five rows in each group. `tally`, like `summarize`, automatically removes the last group.

In the ggplot call I now use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` and I explicitly specify that the y-variable is `n` (n is created by `tally`).

`geom_bar` plots the count of observations per x-variable, geom_col plots a y-variable value for each value of the x-variable.

`scales = "free_x"` removes values from the x-axis that are present in one cut panel but not another.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  tally(sort = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= 5)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = color, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(.~cut, scales = "free_x")
```

Comment: Similar to the first answer, does the same job. Thanks!